# How to get an average of words from a list?

Tags: r, list, for-loop, mean

How do I calculate the average number of words in a list using for loop in [r](/questions/tagged/r)? I have a list called `mylist` which contains 25 vectors with character quotes on each vector.

Here is my code so far:

```
count <- 0
for (i in mylist[1:25]){
count <- count + i
mean(count)
}
```

But I get this error :

> Error in count + i : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please add some sample data and your expected output.

Comment: Please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example and format your question accordingly.

Comment: This is part of 25 sublists:

`[[1]]
 [1] "A"           "coward"      "is"          "incapable"   "of"         
 [6] "exhibiting"  "love;"       "it"          "is"          "the"        
[11] "prerogative" "of"          "the"         "brave."     `  

`[[2]]
 [1] "A"          "man"        "never"      "tells"      "you"        "anything"  
 [7] "until"      "you"        "contradict" "him."    `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `lengths` to get the `length` of each `vector` in the `list` and then wrap with `mean`

```
mean(lengths(mylist))
```

---

If we need a loop, then create a vector to store the `length`

```
v1 <- numeric(length(mylist))
for(i in seq_along(mylist)) v1[i] <- length(mylist[[i]])
mean(v1)
```

Comment: We need to use for loops as part of the homework requirement

Comment: @Pinaypy updated with a loop.  Please let me know if that works for you